# How can I subtract 2 arrays (Eltwise) in Caffe?

Tags: caffe, onnx

I'm trying to convert ONNX to Caffe. and I encountered Eltwise Subtract layer. How can I convert it?

I tried to searh online but found nothing.

One solution I was thinking is scale and Add. But, if there is a better solution, please let me know.